# Editor.js links don't have anchor tag

Tags: javascript, editorjs

I wonder that editorjs has feature that wraps link with anchor? I think this is important for writers etc. Are there any workaround solution for that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add "inlineToolbar" in EditorjsTools.js file.
Ex.

```
const Editor_js_tools = {
   paragraph : {
     class : Paragraph,
     inlineToolbar : true
   }    
}
```

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. The main problem in here is "links are not working when we are writing".

Answer (score 0):

The editor does not provide this functionality. In that case, your link is merely text inside a paragraph. If you want to show inline URLs as links you will have to convert them to anchor elements yourself, maybe with a custom Paragraph class.

If you want this to work in every block, you should try to detect the link in any text property of every block and wrap it in an anchor element with the corresponding href. This should work fine as editorjs assumes that inline content inside blocks may have html tags as `<a>`, `<b>` or `<i>`. Also, inline tools should detect your anchor tags and work with them with no problem.